# How can I use a class containing dashes in ng-class of Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

In my Web App, I'm using `ng-class="{highlighted_category: selected === category}"` to highlight an entry when it is selected. Problems occur when I want to use e.g. `pure-menu-selected` because it contains dashes which Angular does not allow for some reason.

`Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '-' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 6 of the expression [{pure-menu-selected: selected === category}] starting at [-menu-selected: selected === category}].`

What would be an elegant way to solve this? Why does Angular not allow dashes in ngClass?

Comment: Can you show us the full part of that AngularJS Code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use single quotes to quote the class name

```
ng-class="{'pure-menu-selected': selected === category}"
```

The reason you can't use dashes unquoted is simple and makes sense. It's essentially the key of an object. It's the same reason a variable name cannot contain dashes.

Say you tried to have a variable name `a-b`. Does that mean a variable named `a-b` or does it mean `a` minus `b`?

Comment: Your solution works and your explanation seems logical. Thanks!
(I can accept your answer in 10 Minutes)

Answer (score 0):

Angular is treating your class as variable and you cannot use dash in variable names. You can return class as string via function in example:

> ng-class="{getHighlightedClass() : selected === category}".

Where getHighlightedClass() you mus to implement in your controller.

By the way you can bind class directly as string. In example:

> ng-class="{'pure-menu-selected' : selected === category}".